# file not write in current file position

Tags: python, file, io

```
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('foo')
    f.seek(0)
    f.read(1)
    print f.tell() # 1
    f.write('bar')
```

I want the result to be `fbar` but it returns `foobar`. Obviously, file does not write at the current file position.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('foo')
    f.seek(0)
    f.read(1)
    m = f.tell() # 1
    f.seek(m)
    f.write('bar')
```

It works as I expect.

why do I need `seek` again while the current file position is already in `1` ?

Answer (score 3):

this is caused by the fact that `open` returns a buffered file object.

When you're reading, it reads all the file behind the scenes because of buffering (because reading char by char from disk is inefficient).

`f.tell()` is coherent with what you've read, but internally when you write, the file pointer is somewhere else, that's why you have to workaround it by forcing the `seek`.

That's only the "why?", but IMHO it's a bug (or a limitation), as `write` should/could use user-known position not internal system position of the underlying unbuffered file.

That's not a problem on read-only or write-only streams, but that's a problem in that interesting case.

So now you know: to `read` after a `write` or `write` after a `read`, always use `seek` even if you think that the position of the file is correct.

As an alternative, you could use `os.open` to make sure buffering isn't involved (with some adaptations for the system calls as `ftell` doesn't exist, you have to seek 0 from current to get current pos):

```
import os

f = os.open('test.txt',os.O_RDWR|os.O_TRUNC)
os.write(f,b'foo')   # b prefix needed, stream is binary
os.lseek(f, 0, os.SEEK_SET)
os.read(f,1)
# print(os.lseek(f, 0, os.SEEK_CUR)) # to seek/get current
os.write(f,b'bar')
os.close(f)
```

you get `fbar` all right in that case (even when disabling the `lseek` statement)

Comment: Thanks, It, works.But `print(os.lseek(f, 0, os.SEEK_CUR))` also `seek` the current file position as well.

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right !! but it also works without it.

Comment: Yes,I found that